# Scope a using declaration, inside a header

Tags: c++, c++14

Unfortunately I'm bound to using a thirdparty macro which assumes that I am within the namespace `thirdparty`. However this macro declares some types which I need to be outside of the `thirdparty` namespace, so I can't use this snippet:

```
namespace thirdparty
{
  TP_MACRO(my_type_name, inner);
}
```

If I did, all of my declared types would be in the `thirdparty::` namespace which won't work.

The issue is that the `TP_MACRO` is using types from inside of the `thirdparty` namespace without qualifying them. To get arround the this I am currently bringing these types into the current scope with using declarations:

```
using thirdparty::type1;
using thirdparty::type2;

TP_MACRO(my_type_name, inner);
```

The downside of this approach is that I'm polluting the global namespace with these types, which is generally bad practice (this code is in a header file).

I can wrap the above snippet in a new namespace (which I am doing), but I would like to know if there is a way to scope these `using` declarations so that after the macro has declared my types, I can remove them from the surrounding namespace?

The `TP_MACRO` is similar to (but is more complex in reality):

```
#define TP_MACRO (name, inner)         \
    typedef type1<inner> type1_##name; \
    typedef type2<inner> type2_##name;
```

It is also subject to change, hence why I would avoid copying it's contents.

Comment: If you put `using thirdparty::type1;
using thirdparty::type2;

TP_MACRO(my_type_name, inner);` in a namespace like `my_types` you can bring them into whatever scope you want using `using my_types::my_type_name;`  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @NathanOliver This is a good solution, but seems like it would require one using declaration per type? I tried to fix that: https://godbolt.org/z/Ymzy5t Could you see any drawbacks to this approach?

Comment: doing `using namespace outer::inner;` is going to bring those inner using statements in as well which defeats the purpose of putting them in a namespace.

Comment: @NathanOliver Which inner using statements? I would like the typedefs defined by the macro to be in the global namespace (for this example) but I want to avoid bringing the types defined in `thirdparty` into the global namespace with them. It seems to achieve this?

Comment: Oops.  Didn't see that in the example.  Yes, that solution would work exactly like you want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring the types in an embedded namespace inside `thirdparty` so that the macro is happy, then alias that namespace so that it's accessible globally:

```
namespace thirdparty::myns {
    TP_MACRO(my_type_name, inner);
}

namespace myns = thirdparty::myns;
```

If you are not using C++17, then use:

```
namespace thirdparty {
    namespace myns {
        TP_MACRO(my_type_name, inner);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes this seems similar (but better) to what I was thinking too! Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

> I can wrap the above snippet in a new namespace (which I am doing)

That's what you should be doing.

> I would like to know if there is a way to scope these using declarations so that after the macro has declared my types, I can remove them from the surrounding namespace?

No.

---

Also I suggest making a recommendation upstream that they improve these macros.

Comment: Haha unfortunately I don't have the influence for those kinds of suggestions yet. Thank you for your answer, what would you say about this approach?: https://godbolt.org/z/Ymzy5t

Comment: I don't understand. You don't have influence to suggest a fix to a broken/suboptimal feature? That doesn't sound like a very well-run project! Everybody should be able to provide feedback, even if it's ultimately not acted on.

Comment: No opinion on that approach I can't really tell what any of this is supposed to do or which bits are under your control. But it's probably fine. Does it work? Does it meet your needs?